# Obtener metadatos en imagenes con formato PNG en android

Tags: java, android

Parte de una aplicacion que estoy desarrollando, tiene que obtener los metadatos de la imagenes para su posterior uso en la misma, hasta ahora lo que estoy usando es [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html), con algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
//..

String filename = "DirectorioDondeEstaElFichero/DSC_.JPG";

  try {
   ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filename);
   FiltroExif(exif);
   //ShowExif(exif);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();

   //..
  }

  //..

  private void FiltroExif(ExifInterface exif){
     String attr="attr ---\n";

     attr += getTagString(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME,         exif);
     attr += getTagString(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE,     exif);
     attr += getTagString(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, exif);
  }

  //..
```

Pero como la documentacion dice en algun punto:

> Esta es una clase para la lectura y escritura de etiquetas Exif en un
>   archivo JPEG.

Existe alguna forma ya conocida para leer los metadatos de un imagen `PNG` ha ser posible sin usar ninguna libreria no proporcionada por andorid, **aunque esto no es un requisito**, tambien me valdria que no fuera proporcionada por android.

**Esto** es comentado por si alguien a realizado algo parecido o le ayuda a proporcionar alguna solucion:

Como ultima opcion seria revisar el codigo de SKIA y tratar de hacer algo por ahi "aunque de ser posible no se si eso seria embarrase las manos *por lo menos en mi caso*"

**UPDATE**:

- No necesito escribir metadatos en la imagen solo leerlos.
- De ser una libreria externa que tenga tiempo de ser creada o usada, para evitar bugs que puedan aparecer en el proceso de uso de la misma (pero no es un requisito).
- Tambien se agradeceria un ejemplo de uso de la misma o enlace a algun tipo de documentacion que indique que funciona para el propocito.(pero no es un requisito).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Que tal [PNGJ](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj/)

Seria algo parecido a esto

```
PngReader pngr = new PngReader(new File(archivoDeImagen));
pngr.getMetadata().getDpi() //obtiene dpi
```

Esta es la clase [Metadata](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj/blob/master/src/main/java/ar/com/hjg/pngj/chunks/PngMetadata.java) puedes ver ahi toda la información que puedes obtener

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar `Metadata Xtractor`, personalmente lo he usado para archivos `.bmp` y funciona perfectamente, estos son los formatos soportados:

```
Exif
IPTC
XMP
JFIF / JFXX
ICC Profiles
Photoshop fields
WebP properties
PNG properties
BMP properties
GIF properties
ICO properties
PCX properties

------------------------------
para PNG files
FileType.Png
------------------------------
para JPEG files
FileType.Jpeg
------------------------------
para TIFF y (mas) RAW files
FileType.Tiff

FileType.Arw
FileType.Cr2
FileType.Nef
FileType.Orf
FileType.Rw2
------------------------------
para Photoshop files
FileType.Psd
------------------------------
para BMP files
FileType.Bmp
------------------------------
para GIF files
FileType.Gif
------------------------------
para ICO files
FileType.Ico
------------------------------
para PCX files
FileType.Pcx
------------------------------
para WebP files
FileType.Riff
------------------------------
para RAF files
FileType.Raf
```

únicamente tienes que crear un objeto `Metadata`

```
Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(urlImagen);
```

e iterar sobre los tags que encuentra:

```
for (Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) {
    for (Tag tag : directory.getTags()) {
        System.out.println(tag);
    }
}
```

Aquí esta la **[documentación](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor)**

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, aunque ya lo tengo implementado usando PNGJ, puede que saque tiempo para emplear esta, pues creo que manejar todas las imagenes con el mismo objetos lo hace mas facil de mantener y leer, pues por lo que vi readMetadata hace la mayor parte en la seleccion del tipo de imagen. Saludos